# Find all records in database that are within a certain distance of a set of lat and long points

Tags: php, mysql, distance, latitude-longitude

I've seen all the examples and here's what I got so far.

my table is simple:

schools (table name)
- School_ID
- lat
- long
- county
- extrainfo

here's my code:

```
<?php

 $con = mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx");



 if (!$con) {

            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

 } else {}



 mysql_select_db("xxx", $con);

 $latitude = "36.265541";

 $longitude = "-119.207153";

 $distance = "1"; //miles



 $qry = "SELECT *, (3958.75 * ACOS(SIN(" . $latitude . " / 57.2958)*SIN(lat / 57.2958)+COS(" . $latitude . " / 57.2958)*COS(lat / 57.2958)*COS(long / 57.2958 - " . $longitude . " / 57.2958))) as distance FROM schools WHERE (3958.75 * ACOS(SIN(" . $latitude . " / 57.2958)*SIN(lat / 57.2958)+COS(" . $latitude . " / 57.2958)*COS(lat / 57.2958)*COS(long / 57.2958 - " . $longitude . " / 57.2958))) <= " . $distance;

 $results = mysql_query($qry);
 if (mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                            print_r($row);
            }
 } else {}

 mysql_close($con);

 ?>
```

but I get this error when I try to run it:

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: That means your query failed. Print the query string and try running it in the command line. That will give you a more detailed picture of the failure.

Answer (score 3):

First, 'long' is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You'll need to enclose it in backticks like so:

```
SELECT `long`,lat FROM schools
```

Full list of reserved keywords can be found here: [Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have access to a tool like phpMyAdmin, I recommend running your query testing there.

Otherwise, try executing this in your code after running mysql_query():

```
print(mysql_errno().' '.mysql_error());
```

That should give you the error code and error message generated by MySQL. The query looks ok other than the keyword issue, but this will tell you definitively.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I recommend you just grab all the lat/long for all the schools and loop through running a Haversine function through your PHP code.

Comment: Assuming that this query is being used to find schools near a given location, I don't think the distances being searched are going to be large enough to require taking the curvature of the earth into account. And the Earth isn't a perfect sphere in any case, so if you wanted a precise measurement, you'd have to use Vincenty's formulas.

Comment: you could optimize this suggestion by creating an enclosing bounding box about the circle defined by the distance == radius, create a SQL query result with fewer results. then do a haversine distance on this set

Comment: @Calvin, I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me exactly. I'm well aware that the Earth isn't a perfect sphere but using Haversine is pretty good and arguably the most common method in applications where absolute precision isn't required. @jottos, perhaps, but just getting them all and doing Haversine will get you a bit closer than what he has now. :)